# Express - res.download with start and end frames

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express with res.download (file.txt)
is there any way to add a start and end strings to that file?

```
    res.download(path.join(__dirname + '/../file.bin'));
```

for example append "START" and "END" to the file

Comment: What do you mean "add start and end strings" -  you mean, append and prepend stuff to the downloaded file, or add some sort of delimiters to the actual payload?

Comment: yes, but without writing to file itself